# Comparing 2 Columns with Criteria in SQL

Tags: sql

I want to return rows where `UniqReversID` is not in `UniqID` in a given month.
I have a query that gives me below output. However, it's very slow to run.

Is there a way to change up my statement to improve performance?

```
Select *  
FROM Table T1  
WHERE T1.Month = 9  
  AND T1.UniqReverseID NOT IN (  
    Select T2.UniqID  
    FROM Table T2  
    Where T2.Month = 9
  )
```

Table

| UniqReverseID | UniqID | Month |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | 2 | 9 |
| -1 | 3 | 9 |
| 9 | 4 | 9 |
| -1 | 5 | 9 |
| 2 | 6 | 9 |
| -1 | 7 | 10 |
| -1 | 8 | 10 |
| 4 | 9 | 10 |
| -1 | 10 | 10 |

Output:

| UniqReverseID | UniqID | Month |
| --- | --- | --- |
| -1 | 3 | 9 |
| 9 | 4 | 9 |
| -1 | 5 | 9 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should:

- use indexes
- and, wherever possible rewrite `IN` with `EXISTS`

Both the above points, but, especially the one about `EXISTS` will increase your performance because it allows your query to run with lazy evaluation. i.e. as soon as we detected the first evidence of truthfulness or falsehood, we exit early without needing to complete the evaluation. When you use `IN` you are forcing it to do a full evaluation of that subexpression.

In the following, I rewrote your `NOT IN` as a `NOT EXISTS`.
Because of the search, I want to do in `NOT EXISTS`, I create a corresponding index to ensure that the search is efficiently done.

```js
const sql = `

-- Data;
Create Table myTable (UniqReverseID INT, UniqID INT, Month INT);
Insert Into myTable VALUES (6, 2, 9);
Insert Into myTable VALUES (-1, 3, 9);
Insert Into myTable VALUES (9, 4, 9);
Insert Into myTable VALUES (-1, 5, 9);
Insert Into myTable VALUES (2, 6, 9);

-- Indexes;
Create Index IX_myTable_001 On myTable (Month, UniqID);

-- Query;
Select *
From   myTable T1
Where  T1.Month = 9
And Not Exists (
        Select 1
        From   myTable T2
        Where  T2.Month  = T1.Month
        And    T2.UniqID = T1.UniqReverseID
);

`;

(async function() {
  for (let stmt of sql.split(/;/g)) {
    stmt = stmt.trim();
    if (!stmt) continue;
    console.log("> " + stmt);
    if (stmt.startsWith("--")) continue;
    let [res] = await alasql([stmt]);
    if (!res || !res.length) continue;
    for (let row of res) console.log(Object.values(row).join("|"));
  }
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alasql@1.7"></script>
```

I ran the above in SQLite. SQLite (like many other databases) has an `EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN` and for the above it says it is using the index twice. Once for the T1 search and again for the T2 search:

```sql
SEARCH TABLE myTable AS T1 USING INDEX IX_myTable_001 (Month=?)
CORRELATED SCALAR SUBQUERY 1
SEARCH TABLE myTable AS T2 USING COVERING INDEX IX_myTable_001 (Month=? AND UniqID=?)
```

Comment: Sql Server generates the same execution plan for both NOT IN and NOT EXISTS queries using above setup. Adding an index should help anyway.